# How to copy data on azure from one resource group to another?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-storage-account

I have access to two resource groups on azure, one with owner rights and one with contributor right. When I try copying data from a third resource group whose I have no rights through:

```
azure cp 'link_of_blob/file_to_be_copied_with_public_access' 'link_of_container_where_i_want_to_copy'
```

I can do the above where I have owner rights, but I am unable to do so where I have contributor right. What part am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to achieve the goal by assigning appropriate roles, otherwise you may not have permission to operate.

Please note that the contributor role cannot access data, while the owner role can access data.

Have a look of this Offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#all

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, the role you need to be granted is "[Storage Blob Contributor Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor)".
This role gives read, write and delete permissions to the storage containers and blobs.

On the other side, Contributor gives access to the management place (the resource itself) and not its content (blobs).